My shell script wont run, what did i do wrong?
#!bin/bash
Awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $5, $6}' Notes_Dealer_Schedule.txt > Dealer_Schedule_by_time.sh
Var $1 Dealer_Schedule


I know I'm forgetting something here.

What's the error? What is Var $1 Dealer_Schedule, is it part of the output? Please explain what you did, what message you got and format the question appropriately by selecting the script (and potential output) and clicking on the {} button; On the other hand, I can see a mistake right away in Awk which should by all means by awk unless you aliased it.

Error is awk: fatal: can't open source file '{print 1256}' for reading (no such file or directory) I need the script to analysis the dealer schedules by day and time.

Did you put all that on one line?  I thought
#!bin/bash should be the first line by itself.

Ok but please again, format your question so that we can clearly understand what's going on, I don't think the script you posted is the exact copy of what you ran, because Awk should throw a "command not found" error, so please copy paste, and format accordingly, the following into your question 1. The exact script you ran 2. The output you got 3. The contents of Notes_Dealer_Schedule.txt (or a sample of it in case the file is more than, say, 30 lines) 4. An example of the expected output. Thanks

you forgot to include a dir before the file. or execute it at te wrong location.

#!bin/bash
Needs to have the full path to bash,
To be correct and "working" it needs to be #!/bin/bash (note the missing initial /)
Awk -F" " '{print $1, $2, $5, $6}' Notes_Dealer_Schedule.txt ...
The actual command is awk, in lower case,
the present Awk is expected to generate Command 'Awk' not found, ...
... > Dealer_Schedule_by_time.sh Var $1 Dealer_Schedule
Really creating a file named ...sh ?
I'd expect the > to be wrong, and most likely need to change into a | (pipe) symbol,
which then makes Var $1 Dealer_Schedule seem plausible arguments to that script.
